# Ubuntu 13.04 weird partition shown in Gparted

Tags: 13.04, gparted, partitioning

My Ubuntu is a bit slow to boot so I started to look at partitions and with Gparted I have found a weird format partition. Here is a picture!

[image]

Here is a picture of the Gparted partitions !

[image]

explanations:
Ubuntu is inside `dev/sda3` partition and the strange 3gb partition is inside the Linux partition so I am wondering what it could be and if I can erase it safely. 
What about the unallocated spaces? Why are they there and could they slow down my system?
thanks a lot

EDIT: I have found this thread where they suggest defragmenting with windows but since it is a partition inside the ubuntu partition I am wondering if it will do any good:
http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=13447

Comment: `/dev/sda3` is not your Linux partition. Your Ubuntu is not "inside" `sda3`, your Ubuntu is installed on `/dev/sda7`. `sda3` is just an extended partition...which is actually not a partition. For the time being, pretend it's not there. If your Ubuntu is functioning normally, then `/dev/sda5` (the strange partition) can be safely removed, because it's not "mounted" somewhere (i.e. it's not being used by Ubuntu).

Comment: You may want to do a thorough defragment using Defraggler software in Windows. Then reboot and see if the partition is listed in Windows. Before deleting it, try to investigate its contents to see if there's any data you need or Windows needs (it probably has nothing to do with Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/dev/sda3` is an extended partition, which is just a placeholder for the logical partitions inside it. Extended partitions don't really "belong" to any given OS, although it's possible to create an extended partition and then populate it with logical partitions that belong to just one OS. That's not the case on your disk, though.

I disagree with the suggestion by Alaa that you can safely delete `/dev/sda5`. As an NTFS partition, `/dev/sda5` is almost certainly a Windows partition, so its non-use by Linux is irrelevant. Instead, I recommend you evaluate its utility, or lack thereof, from Windows. You might be better to ask about it on a Windows forum -- but be aware that many Windows users are clueless about Linux and about the needs of a multi-boot computer; they may offer bad advice based on this poor understanding of such issues.

Comment: I have booted my computer on windows and I realised that the partition is a D partition from windows so luckily I have not deleted it. I defragmented everything but this partition is still not recongised by gparted but I think I will leave it for now. I still find it strange that this partition has been placed inside the extended partition. I have installed ubuntu after widows and that is when the extended partition has been created. Thank you for the reply and also thanks to those who commented

Comment: Try using `CHKDSK` (or its GUI equivalent) from Windows. That might remove the errors you see in GParted.